# Adding an apostrophe into a dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I would like to ask how can I add an apostrophe into a dynamic SQL. I need to return an SQL statement in one of the columns which has to have apostrophes in itself.

I have the following statement:

```
SET @SQL_String = N'INSERT INTO #ReturnTable
    (
    TableName,
    ColName,
    SQL_Statement,
    Value
     )
VALUES
    (
    ''' + @TableName + ''',
    ''' + @ColName + ''',
    ''' +
         'SELECT ' + 
             @ColName +
         ' FROM ' +
             @TableSchema + '.' + @TableName +
         ' WHERE ' + 
             @ColName + ' = ' + CAST(@GuidArgument AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ';' +''',
        (
        SELECT
            ' + @ColName + '
        FROM
            ' + @TableSchema + '.' + @TableName +
       ' WHERE '
            + @ColName + ' = ''' + CAST(@GuidArgument AS NVARCHAR(50)) + 
       '''))';
```

Executing with:

```
EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[GetLocationOfGuidPre] 'F2CAB996-F00F-43B8-A67A-0000721A829D'
```

I need to put a whole first CAST into a pair of '.

I've tried:

- Putting whole `CAST` statement into a separeted variable like: `DECLARE @Test NVARCHAR(50);`

  - `SET @Test = CAST(@GuidArgument AS NVARCHAR(50));`
  - `SET @Test = 'CAST(@GuidArgument AS NVARCHAR(50))';`
  - `SET @Test = '''CAST(@GuidArgument AS NVARCHAR(50))''';`
- Addidng two more apostrophes:

  - `' WHERE ' + @ColName + ' = ''' + CAST(@GuidArgument AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ''';'`

Comment: Can you [strip your example down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to less fields to better illustrate the question's core?

Comment: Well, I hope now it is better.

Comment: Are you saying the `@GuidArgument` argument contains apostrophes? If so, I think you will need to do something like `' WHERE ' + @ColName + ' = ''' + REPLACE(CAST(@GuidArgument AS NVARCHAR(50)), '''', '''''') + ''';'` using `REPLACE` to replace each apostrophe with two.

Comment: Pass the constant values in using parameters in `sp_executesql` and never worry about single quotes again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use CHAR(39) instead of typing ' in your dynamic code directly.
Example:

```
declare @my_dynamic_sql nvarchar(max) = 'print char(39);';
exec(@my_dynamic_sql);
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot!