# Dynamic SQL - Insert a variables via INSERT INTO x SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I would like to ask how can I insert a variables into a table using `INSERT INTO x SELECT` statement via dynamic SQL.

I have following table:

```
 |-------------------|-----------------|--------------|-----------------|
 |     TableName     |     ColName     |     Value    |  SQL_Statement  |
 |-------------------|-----------------|--------------|-----------------|
```

I get a content for **Value** column by this query:

```
INSERT INTO #ReturnTable(Value) SELECT TreeHolder FROM prm.Schm_Root WHERE ParentTreeHolderId = 'DD040D31-4591-4658-A02E-A6ED00AB64F2';
```

But I need to fill whole table. Please consider that other values are variables, not SQL queries.

```
SELECT @TableSchema = TableSchema FROM #TableNames WHERE Id = @Counter;
SELECT @TableName = TableName FROM #TableNames WHERE Id = @Counter;
SELECT @ColName = ColName FROM #TableNames WHERE Id = @Counter;
SET @SQL_Statement = 'SELECT ' + @ColName + ' FROM ' + @TableSchema + '.' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @ColName + ' = ' + '''''' + CAST(@GuidArgument AS NVARCHAR(50)) + '''''' + ';';
```

Now I have this query that fills a table:

```
SET @SQL_String = N'INSERT INTO #ReturnTable SELECT
''' + @TableName + ''',
''' + @ColName + ''',
''' + @SQL_Statement + ''',
'' + Value + '',
   (SELECT ' +
       @ColName + '
    FROM ' +
       @TableSchema + '.' + @TableName + '
    WHERE ' +
       @ColName + ' = ''' + CAST(@GuidArgument AS NVARCHAR(50)) + '
'')';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL_String
PRINT @SQL_String;
```

The thing I need is to rewrite this query from `INSERT INTO ? VALUE` to `INSERT INTO ? SELECT` format.

Comment: This is a follow up to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888923/adding-an-apostrophe-into-a-dynamic-sql

Comment: Yeah, but the question is totally different.

Comment: I'm mentioning it for others for reference. Though, for me your question is unclear. You need an INSERT with SELECT not with VALUES, but I don't see insert with values in here. Also, you didn't specify how you declare your variables.

Comment: Oh, okay. I did some edit, it is clear for you now?

Comment: From your question, you seem to want to use dynamic sql.

Comment: Oh! That's really my bad. Yes I want to use dynamic SQL, the code in question is now corrected.

Comment: Please please please quote your Strings and parametrise your variables! SQL injection is not your friend! [Why `QUOTENAME` is important](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/QUOTENAME()/176104/)

Comment: Is the `Id` column value not duplicate in the `#TableNames`

Comment: @Larnu I'm going to manage that after I solve this, thanks.
@D-Shih No, `Id` is unique.

Comment: @Chyu manage it when you write the SQL, not later. There is never a good reason for poor Dynamic SQL practices

Comment: Well okay, thanks, I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to insert SQL execute syntax string and it results in `ReturnTable` table.

I would let subquery SQL execute syntax save in a variable. because the will be more clear what you need to do.

Declare a new variable `@SQL_excuteStatement` variable to save your execute syntax.

the `@SQL_Statement` to carry the original SQL string.

```
set @SQL_Statement =  'SELECT ' + @ColName + 
     ' FROM ' + @TableSchema + '.' + @TableName + 
     ' WHERE ' + @ColName + ' = '+'''''' +  CAST(@GuidArgument AS NVARCHAR(50)) + '''''';
```

and use  `select ... from` table instead of subquery in `select`

There is a sample for you.

```
DECLARE @SQL_String NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TableSchema NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColName NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Counter int = 1
DECLARE @SQL_Statement NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @GuidArgument INT = 1

CREATE TABLE TableNames(
     ID INT,
     TableSchema NVARCHAR(100),
     TableName NVARCHAR(100),
     ColName  NVARCHAR(100)
);


CREATE TABLE ReturnTable(
     TableName NVARCHAR(100),
     ColName  NVARCHAR(100),
     SQL_Statement NVARCHAR(max),
     value nvarchar(max)
);


INSERT INTO TableNames VALUES (1,'dbo','T','val');

CREATE TABLE T(val INT);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1)

SELECT @TableSchema = TableSchema FROM TableNames WHERE Id = @Counter;
SELECT @TableName = TableName FROM TableNames WHERE Id = @Counter;
SELECT @ColName = ColName FROM TableNames WHERE Id = @Counter;


set @SQL_Statement =  'SELECT ' + @ColName + 
 ' FROM ' + @TableSchema + '.' + @TableName + 
 ' WHERE ' + @ColName + ' = '+ '''''' +  CAST(@GuidArgument AS NVARCHAR(50)) + '''''';


SET @SQL_String =  N'INSERT INTO ReturnTable (TableName,ColName,SQL_Statement,value) 
SELECT '''+ @TableName + ''','''+ @ColName + ''','''+ @SQL_Statement + '''' + ',' + QUOTENAME(@ColName) +
' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableSchema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '' +
' WHERE ' + @ColName + ' = ''' +  CAST(@GuidArgument AS NVARCHAR(50)) + '''';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL_String
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ba5d64ce3a093fb2ecb1c0338859759f)

**Note**

I would suggest you use clear column after `insert into`

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: @Chyu Wait a moment I got the problem I am writing a solution for it.

Comment: @Chyu you can try this. select from table instead of subquery in `select` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ba5d64ce3a093fb2ecb1c0338859759f

Comment: You are the real MVP! Thanks a lot! <3

Comment: @Chyu No problem glad to help :)

Comment: Can you please update your topic with a solution you have made? I've marked it as an answer.